# Dataframe within a Dataframe - to create new column_

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

For the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'list_A':[3,3,3,3,3,\
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]})
```

How can 'list_A' be manipulated to give 'list_B'?

Desired output:

|  | list_A | list_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | 4 | 1 |
| 9 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 4 | 1 |
| 11 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | 4 | 0 |
| 13 | 4 | 0 |
| 14 | 4 | 0 |
| 15 | 4 | 0 |
| 16 | 4 | 0 |

As you can see, if List_A has the number 3 - then the first 3 values of List_B are '1' and then the value of List_B changes to '0', until List_A changes value again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df['list_B'] = df['list_A'].gt(df.groupby('list_A').cumcount()).astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    list_A  list_B
0        3       1
1        3       1
2        3       1
3        3       0
4        3       0
5        2       1
6        2       1
7        2       0
8        2       0
9        2       0
10       2       0
11       2       0
12       4       1
13       4       1
14       4       1
15       4       1
16       4       0
17       4       0
18       4       0
19       4       0
20       4       0
21       4       0
22       4       0
23       4       0
```

**EDIT**

```
blocks = df['list_A'].ne(df['list_A'].shift()).cumsum()
df['list_B'] = df['list_A'].gt(df.groupby(blocks).cumcount()).astype(int)
```